# Check remote directory using PHP SSH2

Tags: php, ssh

How can I check if a directory 'xyz' exist in the remote SSH server using PHP-SSH2?

Comment: Check the manual here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

Comment: and exchange keys or you'll need to supply a username/password to your php script to work. If you exchange keys, take into account that you'll need to do that with the apache user if you execute the script via apache.

Comment: i am not talking about the ssh connection establishment. I need to check specific directory that might exist in the server after the connection.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use file_exists using sftp prefixing 'ssh2.sftp://'

For example, with an stablished connection you can:

```
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$fileExists = file_exists('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . '/home/marco');
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend abandoning PHP SSH2 in lieu of [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Among other things, PHP SSH2's API sucks. Private keys have to be saved on the filesystem to be loaded whereas with phpseclib all they need be is strings. You can take a key from $_POST without having to dump it to the filesystem as libssh2 requires. To top it off, libssh2 requires you have a separate file for the publickey, which is brain dead, since the private key *contains* the public key.

ssh2_exec(), from libssh2, also returns ANSI color codes and sometimes never returns output and sometimes does (it's inconsistent).

Finally, phpseclib is [just plain faster](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/#comment_3759).

Comment: `phpseclib` is NOT faster when it comes to auth with private key. Using a decent key strength can result in connects taking 10+ seconds. `private key contains the public key`, this is wrong. This doesn't change the fact that the public key isn't required for ssh. I dislike ssh2 limited key-as-filepath, but it doesn't hurt the security of the module and can easily be wrapped using function to create a temp file. `phpseclib` is great if you don't care about speed or CPU usage, but I would say as a person who used both extensively, `ssh2` is much faster and bugfree.

Comment: phpseclib had an update a few months ago that should speed up private key auth a ton. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/math/intro.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

assuming is a linux server

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$cmd = 'if test -d "/YOUR_DIRECTORY"; then echo 1; fi';
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 $connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
 ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

 $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

 $stream = file_exists("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file");
 ?>
```